# Box color won't change during the for loop. (Tables as parameters in functions)

Tags: for-loop, lua, love2d

The latest problem is described at the bottom. (Tables and functions)

GIF: [http://i.imgur.com/jZ9zmbG.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/jZ9zmbG.gifv)

So during the for loop, I am trying to save the info of collided boxes, then apply it when collision is not happening, in this case I need the boxes to keep their original colors generated by math.random() if there is no collision.

In case of collision I simply change the color values of the collided box to red (255, 0, 0).

I am pretty certain the problem lies in the for loop and if statement block.
I'll post rest of the script at the bottom. This is the block:

```
function movePlayer(dt)
  player.pos.x, player.pos.y, cols, cols_len = world:move(
    player, 
    player.pos.x + player.velocity.x *dt, 
    player.pos.y + player.velocity.y *dt)
  for i=1, cols_len do 
    local col = cols[i].other
    local previousColors = {r, g, b}
    local previousBox 
    if cols[i].other then -- if collision is detected then
      lovebird.print(string.format("%s collided with %s's box.", player.name, cols[i].other.name))
      previousBox = i -- store collided box id
      previousColors.r = cols[previousBox].other.color.r -- store color value of the previous collided box
      previousColors.g = cols[previousBox].other.color.g --
      previousColors.b = cols[previousBox].other.color.b --
      cols[i].other.color.r = 255 -- change the color of collided box to red
      cols[i].other.color.g = 0 --
      cols[i].other.color.b = 0 --
      -- debug info --
      lovebird.print(string.format("previousColors: %d, %d, %d, previousBox: %d.", 
      previousColors.r,
      previousColors.g,
      previousColors.b,
      cols[i].other.name))
    else -- if collision is not detected then
      cols[previousBox].other.color.r = previousColors.r -- change color back to the previously saved one
      cols[previousBox].other.color.g = previousColors.g --
      cols[previousBox].other.color.b = previousColors.b --
    end
  end
end
```

Whole script:

```
bump = require 'bump'
player = require 'player'
vector = require 'vector'
timer = require 'timer'
center = vector.new(lg.getWidth()/2, lg.getHeight()/2)
anim8 = require  'anim8'
lovebird = require 'lovebird'
local world = bump.newWorld()
local player = playerNew('sakvojaz', center, 50)

function randomColor()
  return math.random(64, 255)
end

function drawBox(box)
  love.graphics.setColor(box.color.r, box.color.g, box.color.b, 70)
  love.graphics.rectangle('fill', box.pos.x, box.pos.y, box.w, box.h)
  love.graphics.setColor(box.color.r/2, box.color.g/2, box.color.b/2)
  love.graphics.rectangle('line', box.pos.x, box.pos.y, box.w, box.h)
end

function drawPlayerBox(box, r, g, b)
  love.graphics.setColor(r, g, b, 70)
  love.graphics.rectangle('fill', box.pos.x, box.pos.y, box.w, box.h)
  love.graphics.setColor(r/2, g/2, b/2)
  love.graphics.rectangle('line', box.pos.x, box.pos.y, box.w, box.h)
end

function movePlayer(dt)
  player.pos.x, player.pos.y, cols, cols_len = world:move(
    player, 
    player.pos.x + player.velocity.x *dt, 
    player.pos.y + player.velocity.y *dt)
  for i=1, cols_len do 
    local col = cols[i].other
    local previousColors = {r, g, b}
    local previousBox 
    if cols[i].other then -- if collision is detected then
      lovebird.print(string.format("%s collided with %s's box.", player.name, cols[i].other.name))
      previousBox = i -- store collided box id
      previousColors.r = cols[previousBox].other.color.r -- store color value of the previous collided box
      previousColors.g = cols[previousBox].other.color.g --
      previousColors.b = cols[previousBox].other.color.b --
      cols[i].other.color.r = 255 -- change the color of collided box to red
      cols[i].other.color.g = 0 --
      cols[i].other.color.b = 0 --
      -- debug info --
      lovebird.print(string.format("previousColors: %d, %d, %d, previousBox: %d.", 
      previousColors.r,
      previousColors.g,
      previousColors.b,
      cols[i].other.name))
    else -- if collision is not detected then
      cols[previousBox].other.color.r = previousColors.r -- change color back to the previously saved one
      cols[previousBox].other.color.g = previousColors.g --
      cols[previousBox].other.color.b = previousColors.b --
    end
  end
end

function drawPlayer()
  drawPlayerBox(player, 0, 0, 255)
end

blocks = {}

local function addBlock(name, x, y, w, h, r, g, b)
  local block = {name=name, w=w, h=h}
  block.pos = {x=y, y=y}
  block.color = {r=r, g=g, b=b}
  blocks[#blocks+1] = block
  world:add(block, block.pos.x, block.pos.y, w, h)
end


for i=1, #blocks do 
  blocks[i] = addBlock()
end


local function drawBlocks()
  for _,block in ipairs(blocks) do
    drawBox(block)
  end
end

function love.load()
  world:add(player, player.pos.x, player.pos.y, 32, 32)

  for i=1,3 do
    addBlock(i, math.random(100, 600),
              math.random(100, 400),
              math.random(10, 100),
              math.random(10, 100), 
              randomColor(),
              randomColor(),
              randomColor()
    )
  end
end

function love.update(dt)
  --------------------------
  lovebird.update() -- console debug stuff
  --------------------------

  cols_len = 0
  player.Update(dt)
  movePlayer(dt)
end

function love.draw()
  drawPlayer()
  love.graphics.setColor(255, 255, 255, 255)
  player.Draw()
  drawBlocks()
end
```

So my guess is that the "i" iterator in the for loop is just an amount of collisions detected. Since I need to keep track of what table is what, I came up with this idea:

```
local function addBlock(id, x, y, w, h, r, g, b)
  local block = {}
  block[id] = {name=id, w=w, h=h}
  block[id].pos = {x=y, y=y}
  block[id].color = {r=r, g=g, b=b}
  blocks[#blocks+1] = block[id]
  world:add(block[id], block[id].pos.x, block[id].pos.y, w, h)
end
```

I would pass an id (number) in the function and assign it to the table.
That way I could access each table individually like this:

```
previousBox = cols[i].other[id].name
```

But the problem is that I get this error: attempt to index global 'block' (a nil value)

This is where the problem lies I think:

```
function drawBox(box, id)
  love.graphics.setColor(box[id].color.r, box[id].color.g, box[id].color.b, 70)
  love.graphics.rectangle('fill', box[id].pos.x, box[id].pos.y, box[id].w, box.h)
  love.graphics.setColor(box[id].color.r/2, box[id].color.g/2, box[id].color.b/2)
  love.graphics.rectangle('line', box[id].pos.x, box[id].pos.y, box[id].w, box[id].h)
end
```

How do I pass the table with correct index to the function?
I am pretty sure there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you initialize variables right in the `for` loop, because at each iteration you erase the values of `previousColors` and `previousBox`, try to do this before the loop:

```
function movePlayer(dt)
  player.pos.x, player.pos.y, cols, cols_len = world:move(
    player, 
    player.pos.x + player.velocity.x *dt, 
    player.pos.y + player.velocity.y *dt)
    local previousColors = {r, g, b}
    local previousBox
  for i=1, cols_len do
    if cols[i].other then -- if collision is detected then
      lovebird.print(string.format("%s collided with %s's box.", player.name, cols[i].other.name))
      previousBox = i -- store collided box id
      previousColors.r = cols[previousBox].other.color.r -- store color value of the previous collided box
      previousColors.g = cols[previousBox].other.color.g --
      previousColors.b = cols[previousBox].other.color.b --
      cols[i].other.color.r = 255 -- change the color of collided box to red
      cols[i].other.color.g = 0 --
      cols[i].other.color.b = 0 --
      -- debug info --
      lovebird.print(string.format("previousColors: %d, %d, %d, previousBox: %d.", 
      previousColors.r,
      previousColors.g,
      previousColors.b,
      cols[i].other.name))
    else -- if collision is not detected then
      cols[previousBox].other.color.r = previousColors.r -- change color back to the previously saved one
      cols[previousBox].other.color.g = previousColors.g --
      cols[previousBox].other.color.b = previousColors.b --
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah, seems to be the case. I'll confirm as soon as I get home, thanks!

Comment: @sakvojaz You are welcome. If my answer is really useful to you, please accept it.